# What is the fastest MTG Mill deck that can be made?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I have been working on putting together a Mill deck and it occurred to me that there are likely much faster Milling decks out there. So, what is the fastest Milling win condition that can be achieved?

Deck limitations: Standard 4-card limit, and all cards except those from the Un-sets (Unglued and Unhinged) are legal.

Goal: Fastest win by Milling

Other considerations: You have perfect luck (you always draw the cards you need), your opponent won't be doing anything to disrupt you, your opponent has a 60-card deck that is susseptible to milling (ie. doesn't have any of the "shuffle your graveyard into your library" cards)

Also, if this sort of question isn't appropriate for this site, please let me know.

Comment: Poke. Cdeszaq, you've now seen multiple takes on a turn-1 combo kill. I think it's time to accept an answer. ;)

Comment: Heh, sry. my bad :) fixed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Opening hand:

- [Leyline of the Void](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205013)
- [Helm of Obedience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=184550)
- 2 [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221510)s
- 1 Swamp

Turn 1:

Start with Leyline of the Void on the battlefield. Play a Swamp, then a Dark Ritual. Use one black mana to play another Dark Ritual. You will now have BBBBB in your pool. Play the Helm of Obedience and activate it for 1 mana. Your opponent's entire deck will be milled out because none of the cards ever goes to the graveyard.

Had someone use this against me in MTGO once and it took me a minute to work out how it had happened. Takes some serious luck to get this going on Turn 1, but if you can pull it off, it's definitely fun.

Comment: That is so beautifully wrong and evil.

Answer (score 26):

Activating the [Grindstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4610) when you have a [Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=146022&type=card) in play will mill an opponent's entire library in a single shot. The scarecrow turns all cards that aren't in play a single shared color; the Grindstone mills two cards from your opponent — and if those cards share at least one color, it recurs.

Comment: My first thought too.

Comment: That's disgusting.

Comment: This answer would be more complete if you offer one or many ways to get 3 mana on turn one.

Comment: @Sparr Three is not enough, you would need another three to activate the Grindstone's ability. So, two Black Loti FTW!

Answer (score 16):

To cite a famous example, this is actually how the [Tolarian Academy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTolarian%20Academy%5d) decks of Urza-block standard and extended worked. Here's a [sample decklist](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/daily/bb45), played by Tommi Hovi to win PT Rome (the first major tournament at which this sort of deck was legal):

- 4  [Ancient Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4636)
- 3  [City of Brass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220963)
- 4  [Tolarian Academy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8883)
- 4  [Tundra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202424)
- 4  [Volcanic Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202442)
- 3  [Abeyance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4563)
- 3  [Intuition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4707)
- 4  [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4614)
- 4  [Mana Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202538)
- 3  [Mind over Matter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6076)
- 4  [Mox Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5193)
- 3  [Power Sink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26658)
- 2  [Scroll Rack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4628)
- 4  [Stroke of Genius](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5677)
- 4  [Time Spiral](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=10423)
- 3  [Voltaic Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5547)
- 4  [Windfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=7168)

This deck can easily put together a first-turn win, and all it needs is an above-average number of Lotus Petals and Mox Diamonds, which while unlikely, did happen often enough to get about a quarter of this deck banned. Here's a (hopefully somewhat realistic) example turn:

1. Opening hand:
   [Tolarian Academy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8883),
   2x [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4614),
   [Mox Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5193),
   [Voltaic Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5547),
   [Tundra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202424),
   [Windfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=7168)
2. Play **Lotus Petal** #1 and **Lotus Petal** #2
3. Play **Mox Diamond**, discarding Tundra
4. Play **Tolarian Academy**
5. Tap Mox Diamond to play **Voltaic Key**
6. Tap Tolarian Academy to play **Windfall**. ({U} floating) Draw 7 cards:
   [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4614),
   [Power Sink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26658),
   [Mana Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202538),
   [Intuition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4707),
   [Voltaic Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5547),
   [Volcanic Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202442),
   [Stroke of Genius](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5677)
7. Play **Lotus Petal** #3 ({U} floating)
8. Play **Mana Vault**
9. Tap Mana Vault for 3 colorless mana ({C}{C}{C} floating)
10. Use Voltaic Key to untap Mana Vault ({C}{C} floating)
11. Tap Mana Vault again for 3 more colorless mana ({C}{C}{C}{C}{C} floating)
12. Play **Voltaic Key** #2 ({C}{C}{C}{C} floating)
13. Use Voltaic Key #2 to untap Mana Vault ({C}{C}{C} floating)
14. Tap Mana Vault again for 3 more colorless mana ({C}{C}{C}{C}{C}{C} floating)
15. Sacrifice Lotus Petal #1 to play **Stroke of Genius** (X=4). Draw 4 cards:
    [Windfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=7168),
    [Mox Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5193),
    [Mana Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202538),
    [Scroll Rack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4628)
16. Play **Mox Diamond** #2, discarding Volcanic Island
17. Tap Mox Diamond #2 to play **Mana Vault** #2
18. Tap Mana Vault #2 and sacrifice Lotus Petal #2 to play **Windfall**. (C floating) Draw 7 cards:
    [Abeyance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4563),
    [Mind over Matter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6076),
    [City of Brass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220963),
    [Mox Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5193),
    [Time Spiral](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=10423),
    [Mana Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202538),
    [Voltaic Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5547)
19. Play **Mana Vault** #3
20. Play **Mox Diamond** #3, discarding City of Brass
21. Tap Mana Vault #3 to play **Voltaic Key** #3 ({C}{C} floating)
22. Use Voltaic Key #3 to untap Mana Vault #3 ({C} floating)
23. Tap Mox Diamond #3 and Mana Vault #3, and sacrifice Lotus Petal #3, to play **Time Spiral**. Draw 7 cards:
    [Abeyance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4563),
    [Intuition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4707),
    [Tundra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202424),
    [Time Spiral](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=10423),
    [Windfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=7168),
    [Tolarian Academy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8883),
    [City of Brass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220963)
    Untap Tolarian Academy.
24. Tap Tolarian Academy to play **Intuition**. ({U}{U}{U}{U}{U}{U} floating) Search for Mind Over Matter.
25. Play **Mind Over Matter**.
26. Use Mind Over Matter, discarding City of Brass, to untap Tolarian Academy.
27. Tap Tolarian Academy for 9 blue mana. ({U}{U}{U}{U}{U}{U}{U}{U}{U} floating)
28. Repeat the last two steps four more times, discarding Abeyance, Tundra, Tolarian Academy, and Time Spiral. (45x{U} floating)
29. Play **Windfall**. (42x{U} floating) Draw 7 cards:
    [Ancient Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4636),
    [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4614),
    [Power Sink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26658),
    [Scroll Rack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4628),
    [Stroke of Genius](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5677),
    2x [Volcanic Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202442)
30. Repeat steps 26-27 six times, discarding everything but Stroke of Genius (96x{U} floating)
31. Play **Stroke of Genius** (X=93) on your opponent, making him/her draw 93 cards.

<sup>Mana symbols should render as images using [this userscript](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/board-games-se-mana-symbols-a-userscript-for-auto-conversion-of-mana-symbols-to).</sup>

Comment: I like that you use the most expensive lands in existence purely as discard fodder. I realize it's a competitive deck without perfect luck, but in the stacked deck case it's pretty funny.

Comment: 'Most expensive lands in existence'?  I suppose in their Beta versions, but I can get my hands on a Tundra much more cheaply than I can a Mishra's Workshop, Bazaar of Baghdad, or even Tabernacle at Pendrell Vale, and Karakas (an uncommon!) is getting close...

Answer (score 14):

With perfect draws, you can **win on the first upkeep of each game**. Basically take any first-turn-kill deck, add [Leyline of Anticipation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20Anticipation%5d) to allow you to play everything at instant speed, add a card that will force your opponent to draw on the spot, and use non-lands for your mana.

Let's go with [the Helm plan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5638) since it's a two-card combo and blanks cards like Emrakul.

Here's an example that can kill your opponent before they even get a single draw step, taking advantage of the entire MTG card pool (Vintage-legal):

Starting hand: [Leyline of Anticipation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20Anticipation%5d), [Leyline of the Void](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20the%20Void%5d), [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d), [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDark%20Ritual%5d), [Helm of Obedience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHelm%20of%20Obedience%5d), [Ancestral Recall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncestral%20Recall%5d), [Mox Sapphire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Sapphire%5d).

Before the first turn:

- Put both your Leylines into play (5 cards in hand).

On the first upkeep (either player's turn):

- Cast Black Lotus, sac it for black mana (4 cards in hand, BBB in your mana pool).
- Cast Dark Ritual (3 cards in hand, BBBBB in your mana pool).
- Cast Helm of Obedience (2 cards in hand, B in your mana pool).
- Activate the Helm with X=1, which will exile your opponent's entire library (2 card in hand).
- Cast and activate Mox Sapphire (1 card in hand, U in your mana pool).
- Cast Ancestral Recall to force your opponent to draw cards, which will win you the game (0 cards in hand).

Answer (score 7):

If you can play any Vintage-legal card and have perfect control over your draws, you can always execute a turn-1 storm combo win off of [Brain Freeze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=47599).

90% of the deck would be the same cards that make up [Vintage Tendrils combo decks](http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/vintage/12009_The_Fastest_Deck_Ever_By_Far_Meandeck_Tendrils_Revisited.html).

*Without* the "perfect draw" assumption, storm combo's probably the strongest first-turn kill deck just because most of the cards are nearly interchangeable. You can get unlucky with too much "draw a card" and not enough "make some mana" or vice versa, but it's more consistent than trying to assemble a classic multi-part combo.

Comment: This is probably the way to go if you want the most effective deck.

Answer (score 2):

Play [Ghost Quarter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghost%20Quarter). Opponent plays a land. Tap Ghost quarter to destroy the land they just played. They search for a land and put it into play. You drop 4 [Archive Trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archive%20Trap)s on them for 52 cards.  If they are running 60 cards, that would be their entire deck.

Comment: If you did this once in a tournament then every future opponent would know not to search for a land after you used Ghost Quarter on them. So, a one turn win, but only once, so not nearly as good as other answers.

Comment: @Sparr is having ghost quarter play as strip mine (in modern no less) really that bad? this concept of deck is reasonably viable in modern, i suggested it in an answer to a similar question

Comment: @Rawrgramming oh, it's surely only slightly less viable due to my objection, but we are already talking about unbelievable odds (you need 5 specific cards in your opening hand for this one), so the difference is notable.

Comment: @Sparr true enough, in terms of turn 1 mill this isnt the avenue to take. in terms of actual viable mill deck for playing in tournaments (at least, in modern), ghost quarter/archive trap is giving your opponent a choice between 2 effects that are very bad for them. A real deck doesnt just play a combo and lands, and this fits in well with a deck that has a mill kill and a general controlling playstyle.

Comment: @Sparr I think it's quite probable that opponent would search anyway, because the odds of you having 4 Archive Traps is very low, while the drawback of not searching for a land is very debilitating (it turns Ghost Quarter into Strip Mine - a card restricted in Vintage).

Answer (score 2):

[Mindcrank](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindcrank), [Duskmantle Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Duskmantle%20Guildmage) and any card that will force opponent to mill at least one card will start an infinite combo loop. They will mill cards and lose life until they run out of cards or lives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I can find (based around the [Halimar Excavator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHalimar%20Excavator%5d) Ally):

Turn 1:

- Island
- [Mothdust Changeling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMothdust%20Changeling%5d)
- Running mill total: 0

Turn 2:

- Island
- Halimar Excavator (mill 2)
- Running mill total: 2

Turn 3:

- Island
- Halimar Excavator (mill 6)
- Mothdust Changeling (mill 8)
- Running mill total: 16

Turn 4:

- Island
- Halimar Excavator (mill 15)
- Halimar Excavator (mill 24)
- Running mill total: 55 (win)

Answer (score 1):

Is it cheating to use three-turn infinite mana combo?

### Opening hand:

[image: Paradise Mantle]
[image: Forest]
[image: Elvish Pioneer]
[image: Island]
[image: Pili-Pala]
[image: Heartstone]

### + One of these:

[image: Blue Sun's Zenith]
[image: Psychic Drain]
[image: Braingeyser]
[image: Stroke of Genius]

1. Turn 1: Play Forest, Paradise Mantle, Elvish Pioneer, Island
2. Turn 2: Draw another land, Play land, Pili-Pala, Equip Paradise Mantle
3. Turn 3: Draw something. Play Heartstone, tap Pili-Pala for [U], Pay [U] to Untap it for [U], repeat (target player's library size + 4) times, (make sure to add a black mana in the cycle if you use Psychic Drain.) Play Psychic Drain, Blue Sun's Zenith, Braingeyser, Stroke of Genius, or whatever other spell that does the trick. Boom.

Comment: It's not cheating, since the "rules" didn't specify against it. However, non-infinite-mana combos are what I was hoping to get. I do like the solution, however, and infinite mana combos are always fun to use.

Comment: I'd take out green entirely, along with the Heartstone and Paradise Mantle, and just use Grand Architect.

Comment: Pili-Pala doesn't have haste either, so this mill deck would require 2 turns to pull off.

Answer (score 1):

No infinite combos, (mostly) red deck, almost 600 cards milled on first turn. But I took you at your word and allowed myself 4 copies of Power 5 cards.

Deck List:

- 4 [Relentless Assault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205271)
- 1 [Through The Breach](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=80250)
- 1 [Enrage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83076)
- 4 [Wheel of Fortune](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202558)
- 1 [Szadek, Lord of Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247390)
- 4 [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d)
- 4 [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLotus%20Petal%5d)
- 4 [Mox Ruby](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Ruby%5d)
- 4 [Mox Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Diamond%5d)
- 1 [Tolarian Academy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8883)
- 4 Mountain

Opening hand: 3 Mox Ruby, 1 Mox Diamond (discard Mountain), Black Lotus, Wheel of Fortune. Play all, tapping 3 Moxes.

Mill count: 7

Draw 7: Mox Ruby, 2 Mox Diamond (discard 2 Mountains), Black Lotus, Wheel of Fortune, play all, tapping 3 Moxes.

Mill count: 14

Draw 7: 1 Mox Diamond (discard Mountain), 2 x Black Lotus, 2 x Lotus Petal, Wheel of Fortune, play all tap last 2 Moxes and sac 1 Lotus Petal.

Mill count: 21

Draw 7: 3x Lotus Petal, Tolarian Academy, tap out, Through the Breach -> Szadek, Wheel of Fortune.

Mill count: 28, 15U, 15R floating

Draw 7: Enrage -> Szadek +13/+0 = 18/5. Attack!

Mill count: 46, 2U 14R floating, Szadek 36/5

Relentless Assault (1) Attack! MC 82, Szadek 72/5

Relentless Assault (2) Attack! MC 154, Szadek 144/5

Relentlass Assault (3) Attack! MC 298, Szadek 288/5

Relentless Assault (4) Attack! MC 586, Szadek 576/5

Answer (score 1):

I've always done four [Mind Sculpt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383313)s plus four [Archaeomancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchaeomancer%5d)s, plus four [Curse of the Bloody Tome](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurse%20of%20the%20Bloody%20Tome%5d). So every upkeep they'd mill 8, and then if you play all the Archaeomancers and Mind Sculpts, that's mill 56.

Answer (score -3):

What always works for me in my mill deck is having cards like [Tome Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTome%20Scour%5d), [Mirko Vosk, Mind Drinker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirko%20Vosk%2c%20Mind%20Drinker%5d) or traumatize to mill a pretty good amount of their deck. In the meantime I have my fog banks and [Kraken Hatchling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKraken%20Hatchling%5d) doing a little blocking while I am searching my library for [Consuming Aberration](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConsuming%20Aberration%5d) using [Diabolic Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiabolic%20Tutor%5d). I then use either [Dying Wish](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDying%20Wish%5d) or [Rite of Consumption](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRite%20of%20Consumption%5d) to sacrifice consuming aberration alowing to do damage equal to its toughness to the opponent.

Dead.